# How do I launch a .pdf programmatically?

Tags: .net, windows, pdf, c++-cli

I have a .pdf help file and would like to launch it from my C++/CLI application.

Currently I do the following:

```
System::Diagnostics::Process::Start("iexplore", "C:\\MyPdf.pdf");
```

...which works but has the irritating side effect of opening it in internet explorer. Is there a way to launch it in whatever the Windows currently uses to open .pdf files?

Comment: Yes, you *told* it to launch in Internet Explorer by specifying `"iexplore"`. :-) Omitting that will cause the system to use the default PDF viewer. If one is not installed, it will ask the user how they wish to open it.

Comment: If you don't want it to open in ie, why specify it? Its only doing what you told it to :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will let the system decide which viewer to use..

```
 System::Diagnostics::Process::Start("C:\\MyPdf.pdf");
```

Comment: Is there any way to check whether Windows has something natively to read the document?

Answer (score 0):

When starting a process without specifying the application to open that file, it will be opened by the default application.

Anyway, if you configure your system to associate the pdf files by PDF file reader applications, then it will be automatically started by the PDF reader application.

You can cross check it by running "start filename.pdf" command in command line.